# Как сделать сжатие кодом хаффмана для текста из файла txt?

Tags: c++, шифрование, txt

[здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/144200/) рассказывается про сам алгоритм
Так выглядит на данный момент вывод сжатия в консоли
[image]

Код для строки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int count;
    char symbol;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node() { }

    Node(char __symbol, int __count)
    {
        symbol = __symbol;
        count = __count;
    }

    Node(Node* l, Node* r) 
    {
        symbol = 0;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        count = l->count + r->count;
    }

    static void Print(Node* root, int depth = 0)
    {
        if (!root) return;

        if (root->symbol)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
                cout << ".";
            cout << root->symbol << endl;
        }
        else depth++;
        Print(root->left, depth);
        Print(root->right, depth);
    }
};

 void BuildTable(Node* root, vector<bool>& code, map<char, vector<bool>>& table) 
{
    if (root->left)
    {
        code.push_back(0); // left
        BuildTable(root->left, code, table);
    }

    if (root->right)
    {
        code.push_back(1); // right
        BuildTable(root->right, code, table);
    }

    if (root->symbol)
        table[root->symbol] = code;
    if (code.size())
        code.pop_back();
}

bool SortNode(const Node* a, const Node* b)
{
    return a->count < b->count;
}

string Decode(string& str, map<vector<bool>, char>& table)
{
    string out = "";
    vector<bool> code;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        code.push_back(str[i] == '0' ? false : true);
        if (table[code])
        {
            out += table[code];
            code.clear();
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    string raw = "SSSPPORTTTT";
    map<char, int> symbols;

    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++)
        symbols[raw[i]]++;

    list<Node*> trees;
    map<char, int>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = symbols.begin(); itr != symbols.end(); itr++)
    {
        Node* p = new Node(itr->first, itr->second); // key = symbol;  value = count
        trees.push_back(p);
    }

    while (trees.size() != 1)
    {
        trees.sort(SortNode);

        Node* l = trees.front();
        trees.pop_front();
        Node* r = trees.front();
        trees.pop_front();

        Node* parent = new Node(l, r);
        trees.push_back(parent);
    }

    Node* root = trees.front();
    root->Print(root);

    vector<bool> code; // buffer
    map<char, vector<bool> > table;
    BuildTable(root, code, table); 

    for (itr = symbols.begin(); itr != symbols.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << itr->first << " - ";
        for (int j = 0; j < table[itr->first].size(); j++)
            cout << table[itr->first][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    string out = "";
    // print coded string
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < table[raw[i]].size(); j++)
        {
            out += table[raw[i]][j] + '0';
            cout << table[raw[i]][j];
        }
    cout << endl;
    cout << out.c_str() << endl;


    // decode
    map<vector<bool>, char> ftable;
    for (auto i = table.begin(); i != table.end(); i++)
        ftable[i->second] = i->first;
    cout << Decode(out, ftable).c_str() << endl;


    while (true);
}
```

Comment: Ссылку вижу, спасибо, почитаю. Так же нету результата. По идее для вашей строки нужно просчитать дерево вручную и сравнить с деревом которое получилось - тогда будет понятно при упаковке ошибка или при распаковке. По повреждениям дерева будет понятно на каком шаге, возможно. Если дерево сошлось - упаковано правильно. А так - можно только гадать где ошика.

Comment: Ошибки вроде как нет, не могу сообразить как сделать алгоритм для текстового файла. Для строки всё работает.

Comment: А в строку же ведь можно прочесть весь текстовый файл? Тогда я упустил этот момент, ваш вопрос сводится к вопросу как прочесть текстовый файл в строку, и хаффман тут непричём.

Comment: здесь нужно именно импортировать по типу fout.open("filename.txt");

Comment: Можно так https://coderoad.ru/15547645/C-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает!!!!!!!